# Error synchronizing data with database Reason: SQL Error [932] [42000]: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB

Tags: oracle, blob, dbeaver

I have this table in oracle db :

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 NAME                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32)
 GROUP                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32)
 REVISION                                  NOT NULL NUMBER(11)
 VERSION                                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(32)
 ID                                             NUMBER(10)
 DATA                                               BLOB
 TIME_STAMP                                         TIMESTAMP(3)
```

when I try to edit the blob cell in Dbeaver it's not saving it. I don't understand why,
I have an XML file in the blob column so update by command its not a good option.
please suggest what can be the problem

Comment: Why would you store an XML document in a BLOB column? That's what `xmltype` is for.

Comment: since this column contain many types of bi files not only XML.